# Black windows issue

Tags: gtk

I develop a web browser based on gtk+ and webkit2gtk in Rust and sometimes, all GTK+ windows become black.

Even the gtk inspector window that we get with the environment variable `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` is black.
Even thought the windows are black, the UI is still responsive since I can navigate the web with the keyboard (I see the window title updating, showing the new page URL and load progress).

Here are two actions that triggers this issue everytime they happen:

- Destroying the web view
- When running the application a second time, it sends a message via Unix Domain Socket to the first process so that it creates a new web view.

I have unfortunately no small example to reproduce the issue. If you want, I can show you the code of the project, but it is big, non-trivial and uses many abstraction layers over gtk+.

I know I don't give you a lot to help me, but if you can give me some explanations about how the rendering works and how to debug that, it would be very appreciated.

Can you give me some hints on how to debug this issue?

Is there a global OpenGL (or whatever) context for the GTK+ windows?

Are there some debuging tools to help me? (Setting `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all` does not show anything relevant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `strace`, I was able to debug this issue:
I found out the FD used for IPC communication was still polled after being closed, so it was returning `POLLNVAL`.
Removing the FD with `g_source_remove_unix_fd()` fixed this issue.